# Activerecord model method passed to ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeresource

Using activeresource, I'm pulling an activerecord model from another application. This model does a less than simple method pulling results from several associations. How do I pass the result of this method with the activeresource call. I've tried adding it to the activeresource schema, and I'm sure I could do it with a custom route, or do that method messily in the activeresource model, but I'd prefer to just have it passed with the original call to the model.

Example:

app1: activeresource model RemoteModel

app2: activerecord model MyModel

MyModel responds to the method run_calculation_on_several_associations

How do I get 'run_calculation_on_several_associations' to RemoteModel simply and directly? Preferably when RemoteModel calls out to MyModel, without running a custom method or route.

Comment: one solution would be to run 'run_calculation_on_several_associations' whenever the results change and then save that as a field in the model, which activeresource would pick up -- but this seems unclean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change the xml/json response on your `MyModel` controller to include the method you want to use.

```
class MyModelController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @my_model.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml { render xml: @user.to_xml(:methods => [ :run_calculation_on_several_associations])}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I remember reading something about this from when rendering json responses.